# option onChange on currentpage using database information

Tags: javascript, php

I've written a query that takes the usernames from the database and puts them in s like this:

```
 <?php
    $username_set = get_all_usernames();

    while ($username = mysql_fetch_array($username_set)){
        echo "<option>" .   $username['username'] . ""  . "</option>";
    }
 ?>
```

That works fine but now I want to add a onchange function to my  tags. I've done it like this:

```
<select name="user_result" onChange="top.location.href = this.form.user_result.options[this.form.user_result.selectedIndex].value,'_self';">
```

That works fine too, it is redirecting to the selected option. But I want to select a option and stay at the same page and display the (coming) information that username contains. But for now printing the username below the  would be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute code on change of a select, it's easy to include this in a javascript function. Not sure if you want the javascript or the jquery solution, so I'll include them both.

Plain javascript:

```
function show_user(data) {
  var el = document.getElementById("show_username").innerHTML = data;
}
```

jQuery solution:

```
function show_user(data) {
  $("#show_username").html(data);
}
```

Then you call this function on the select change:

```
<select name="user_result" onchange="show_user(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option>--select a user--</option>
  <option>username</option>
  <option>username 2</option>
</select>
<div id="show_username">this will update to the selected user name</div>
```

jsfiddle for plain javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/CwFs5/

jsfiddle for jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/5PuX3/